# Use cURL with Kerberos to auth on Keycloak

Tags: authentication, curl, kerberos, keycloak, openid-connect

I have following setup given:

- keycloak server at https://auth.example.com
- AD connection with a LDAP provider configuration
- Kerberos options set in LDAP provider configuration
- authentication with any AD user works
- authentication with Kerberos Tickets **in browser** works

As I know to use cURL with Kerberos auth it looks similar to this:

```
$ curl --negotiate -u : https://app.example.com/index.html
```

One can use Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Type to get an Access-Token in non-interactive manner. But how do I get it using cURL **with a Kerberos ticket** and Keycloak?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example [1] in the official documentation:

```
curl \
  -d "client_id=myclient" \
  -d "client_secret=40cc097b-2a57-4c17-b36a-8fdf3fc2d578" \
  -d "username=user" \
  -d "password=password" \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

- [1] https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_resource_owner_password_credentials_flow
- [2] https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#troubleshooting-2

Comment: I know about this, I updated the question. I would like to use kerberos ticket not ROPC